# How do I add custom records into a query containing a linked table?

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a linked table that contains descriptive information of restaurants such as name, address, city, etc.

```
tbl_Restaurant
REST_SITE_CD (PK)
Restaurant
Address
City
…
```

I have created a query based off of this linked table and a different table that hosts auditing information.

```
tbl_Audit
AuditID (PK)
REST_ID (FK)
Date
…
```

From this query, a form was created to allow the user to easily choose a restaurant by its name and location, and enter in the necessary auditing information.

However, some audited restaurants are not located inside tbl_Restaurants. I would like to manually enter these locations into the query, but the query does not allow me to enter new addresses that do not match an existing primary key in tbl_Restaurant.

The only solution I can think of is to create a redundant table just for unlisted restaurants and combine it with the query later on via a union query or something like that. However, I’m sure this violations a bunch of normalization principles. Additionally, it would be ideal if the custom locations are only reflected upon the query and not the linked table, if that makes any sense.

Any help would be appreciated! Please let me know if there’s any other information I can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Records need to be stored in a table.

You can use a local table, and use a `UNION ALL` to add the records from your local table to the query. However, you can't enter them directly in the query, since union queries are not updateable. You need to add them to the table.

Comment: Thank you Erik - I took the route of creating another table for custom restaurant sites, and doing a union query to combine the custom table with the existing table!